# Why angular2 uses ? and ; as it routing parameter separator?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Angular2 uses matrix notation along with ? and & to separate query parameters.

1) I want to understand why ng2 uses multiple ways of separating query parameters?

2) Is there a way to force ng2 to use only one of the above approaches ?

3) what if I have ; in the parameter's value. Is there a way to turn ; separator off (matrix notation)

Answer (score 0):

- Matrix notation is used for query parameters of the root router
- ? is used for query parameters of child routers, there is no way to force one way, it depends where you add the parameters
- I guess you need to escape it (as `%3B`)